# PHP Server Status code error

Tags: php

I am trying to make a server status page for my game server and the code ends up not showing if the server is online.

```
<?PHP 
$ts_ip = "177.82.148.141"; 
$ts_port = "2505"; 

$output = @fsockopen("$ts_ip", $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);  
stream_set_timeout($output, 00002);

if (!$output) { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#DD0000><B>FEB Offline</B></FONT>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#00DD00><B>FEB Online</B></FONT>"; 
} 
@fclose($output); 
?>
```

It also gives me this error:

> Warning: stream_set_timeout() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u918484727/public_html/teste.php on line 6

May someone help me?

Comment: Remove the `@` at the beginning of `fsockopen`. You'll get more warnings, as `$output` is probably equal to false or something. Find out why `fsockopen` is failing.

Comment: When i remove the @ i have an error '-'

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 177.82.148.141:2505 (Connection timed out) in /home/u918484727/public_html/teste.php on line 5

Comment: For the record `@` is called **error control operator** and will suppress any error generated by an expression. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: is 177.82.148.141 up?

Comment: Well there you go, your task is to find out whether the server is online or not. Add another check to see `if (!$output)` then the server is also offline. I'm also getting a timeout when I attempt to ping `177.82.148.141`. Make sure your server is actually online when you want to test it.

Comment: @supajason Even being turned off was for him to simply say "FEB OFFLINE"

Comment: https://screenpresso.com/=leIEg

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f3rwp4

Comment: @funkygtacat00 you're right so that must mean the fsockopen has an error and this is why is returning a boolean (I'm guessing false) see my answer below

Comment: Are you on PHP 7 ?

Comment: Yes, i am using

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f3s27l

Well I checked port and it is open so I believe it is error in the same code and not in my router

Comment: What's the point of calling `stream_set_timeout()` and then immediately closing it?

Comment: @Barmar I did not understand what you mean

Comment: The purpose of `stream_set_timeout()` is to set a timeout when you perform `read()` operations on the stream. If you never read from the stream, why are you setting a timeout?

Comment: @b.enoit.be Sorry,  i am using php 5.5

Comment: @Barmar :/ well.... i removed the `stream_set_timeout($output, 00002);`
but the code does not fulfill its function of to show if the server is online or offline

Comment: I don't see how that line can make a difference. It doesn't change the value of `$output`. Either `fsockopen()` succeeds or it doesn't. Calling a function after it returns won't change the value of the variable.

Comment: Okay, @Barmar but how would I have to do for him say if my server is online? Because even the ports and everything from my server is working the code does not say "Feb online": /

Comment: Maybe there's a firewall blocking the connection. You need to investigate why the connection isn't working when the server is online.

Comment: But in the port check the connection is up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's probably a better way to handle this but this will make it work.

```
$ts_ip = "177.82.148.141"; 
$ts_port = "2505"; 

$output = @fsockopen($ts_ip, $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2); 

if (!$output) { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#DD0000><B>FEB Offline</B></FONT>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#00DD00><B>FEB Online</B></FONT>";  
    stream_set_timeout($output, 00002);
    @fclose($output); 
}
```

I put `$output` logic in the else so that your code doesn't attempt to use it as a resource when it returns false.

Also, although it isn't the cause of the problem, as supajason pointed out you should probably use $ts_ip instead of "$ts_ip". You should also refactor your code in other ways, such as removing the `@` error suppression.

Comment: Thanks, the code is not giving more error but does not show the "FEB online" when the server is actually online

Comment: The server may be online but port 2505 is definitively closed.

Comment: @PedroLobito :/ http://prntscr.com/f3rzmp i will try make something on the router

Comment: @funkygtacat00 It was offline when I tested it, now it's online and your code works fine.

Comment: @funkygtacat00 is that good or are you expecting it to say online? If you're expecting it to be online, double check every param your passing to fsockopen. $ts_ip, $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2

Comment: @Goose I can't answer you because I kind of did not understand what you meant (google translator is bad and I do not know English)

Comment: Are you still having issues? Check every parameter you are passing to the function fsockopen.

Answer (score 0):

"$ts_ip" shouldn't have " round them?

Comment: The quotes make no difference in this case.